# Azure B2C - Impersonation - List of allowed users that can impersonate a specific user

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I wanted to use the custom impersonation flow in Azure B2C, but I have the following question. Is there a way to declare exactly the users that can impersonate a specific user? For example, I want to declare, that the users that can impersonate the user with the email company@company.com, are the user1, user2, and user3 only.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to approach this problem would be to have a database of the impersonators to impersonatees which is read into B2C via a REST API technical profile.

High level steps:

1. execute impersonation custom policy
2. call rest api `GetEligibleImpersonationAccounts?userId=
3. parse rest api response to string collection
4. display the available accounts to the user

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I had on my mind as an alternative if this couldn't be a part of the flow itself. I would imagine something like having a field in the user's profile page in AAD that will hold this information, instead of creating an external API.

Comment: You can add an [extension attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy), store the values as CSV, and manage it with [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations#application-extension-directory-extension-properties) but string extension attributes are limited to 256 characters so you'll likely run out of space and need to go towards the API solution anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Probably the API solution is the way to go.